# Using Hibernate/JPA with multiple ClassLoaders to access multiple databases

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, classloader

Our application is a middle-tier application that provides a dozen or so front-end application with access to a couple dozen databases (and other data sources) on the back end.

We decided on using OSGi to separate the unrelated bits of code into separate bundles.  This ensures proper code encapsulation and even allows for hot-swapping of specific bundles.

One advantage of this is that any code speaking to a specific database is isolated to a single bundle.  It also allows us to simply drop in a new bundle for a new destination, and seamlessly integrates the new code.  It also ensures that if a single back-end data source is down, that requests to other data sources are unaffected.  One complication is that each of those bundles is loaded by a separate ClassLoader.

We'd like to start using JPA for our new destinations that we're building.  Previously, we have been using JDBC directly to send SQL queries and updates.

We've looked into Hibernate 4, but it seems that it was built on the assumption that everything is loaded using a single ClassLoader.  Switching between ClassLoaders for different bundles does not appear to be something it can handle consistently.

While it seems that Hibernate 5 may have corrected that issue, all the tutorials/documentation I've found for it gloss over the complexities of configuration.  Most simply assume you are using a single application-level configuration file, which will not suit our needs at all.

So, my questions are:

1. Does Hibernate 5 properly handle connecting to multiple databases, with the configuration/POJos for each database loaded by a different ClassLoader?
2. How do we configure Hibernate to connect to multiple databases using multiple ClassLoaders?
3. Is there another JPA framework that might be better suited to our specific needs?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is fine but for OSGi usage you also need an intermediary. In the OSGi specs this is defined by the [OSGi JPA service spec](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.jpa.html). It defines how to connect to a JPA provider in OSGi without a hard reference to it.

This spec is implemented by [Aries JPA](https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa). It also provides additional support for blueprint and [declarative services](https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa/tree/master/examples/tasklist-ds). There is also [Aries transaction control](https://github.com/apache/aries-tx-control) service that takes similar approach to supporting JPA and transactions in OSGi it also uses the core of Aries JPA but is a bit different in usage.

The last part you might need is [pax-jdbc](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/pages/23953600/Documentation) which allows to define a XA datasource just with configuration. The examples already use it.

To get started easily you can use [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/) which has features for all of the above.

Aries JPA allows to use different databases in the same OSGi application.